# Get object_id of the last message

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, restfb

Using FQL, is there a way to get the `object_id` of the last message posted by a user (the `user_id` being known)?

Comment: you mean, the last post made by the user?

Comment: yes, precisely me (my account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, message, 
       substr(post_id, strpos(post_id, "_") + 1, strlen(post_id))
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id = me() AND actor_id=me() 
 LIMIT 1
```

The `stream` table doesn't offer an `object_id` field, which explains why we have to make a little string subtract (`substr`) to get it. Indeed, a `POSTID` is made as such: `USERID_OBJECTID`.

---

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "post_id": "1022361234_10201571234567890", 
      "created_time": 1383606736, 
      "message": "My message", 
      "anon": "10201571234567890"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Used doc:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream